# Django Navigation from Template-Login to a self written index.html

Tags: python, django, authentication, navigation

Im using the Django template login and want to navigate from the login to my own written index.html file.

so if a user push the "login" button the result page is my index file.

My second question is how to use logos in django python and what structure i need in my project.

best regards

Comment: i dont know how i can navigate from the login file to my own page

Comment: do the django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

1: create your own view that the login button take the person to when clicked and load your index.html template.  you do not have to use the built in login.

2: logo? you can use any logo/format you want. Django doesn't come with a template that creates the look of the site (beside the admin one); so you need to create it.

Answer (score 0):

create custom log-in and registration in your project, and write the custom back-end if you have more user ,if request is came from user to log-in then redirect to index,html,

Comment: Can you attempt to format your answer to make it more readable?  As it is, it is hard to understand.